# RxJava 2 Flowable forEach() vs subscribe()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Im currently learning RxJava and i noticed that both forEach and subscribe method pretty much do the same except that with subscribe i have onNext, onError and onComplete,

while on forEach i only have onNext.

Both returns a Disposable.

Is there anything else under the hood on how they behave or is that it?

Comment: `forEach` is an alias for `subscribe` and is provided for discoverability due to such methods available in Java Stream.

Comment: `subscribe` accepts an object of type `Subscriber`.
`forEach` accepts a method (function).
Functional programmers always prefer functions over objects.